# Change Woocommerce pagination permalinks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting, pagination

My Woocommerce Shop uses pretty permalinks but I want to disable it for pagination.

When I visit a Category page and manually add the parameter `„?paged=2“` for example the page does not redirect me to the permalink version.

But as of now the links are generated like `„/page/2“`.

How can I achieve that the parameter version is used on the Category page instead of `„/page/2“`?

Code for the Archive Pages:

```
<?php
    get_header();
    do_action( 'shoptimizer_page_start' );

    ?>

        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    do_action( 'shoptimizer_page_before' );

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                    /**
                     * Functions hooked in to shoptimizer_page_after action
                     *
                     * @hooked shoptimizer_display_comments - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'shoptimizer_page_after' );

                endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

            </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->


    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->

    <?php
    get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing via actual PHP? If so, I'd recommend woo_pagination to control that.

[Woo_pagination documenation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woo_pagination/)

Comment: Can you help me with woo_pagination to get the expected results?

Comment: Do you have example code you can add to the original post? Where are you trying to list links? How are you doing it currently?

Comment: Just added the code of the archive pages hope that was what you were asking for. You can have a look at https://shisha-express.com/shisha-tabak/ which is a Category Archive page containing the pagination.

Comment: So I see the pagination does work, it's just the way it's represented in the address bar that you have an issue with? It's also a Woocommerce theme, so they have their own implementation of those action hooks.

You could always use /page/n to get to whatever page you wanted to. How are you using the links that you need a query string?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I am looking for I want to change the permalink structure to a query string url.

Comment: Right - I'm just asking why. Is there a particular reason you need query strings instead of permalinks?

Also - The code you provided doesn't seem to have the pagination logic in it.

Comment: The reason for this is that Google is indexing our paginated pages and I would prefer using a query parameter url solution instead of making the links nofollow or changing the canonical. As I have seen a lot of big ecommerce sites are having query pagination urls.

Comment: You need to post the php that has the pagination code in it. That would be more use. It may be that the prettify is filtering the pagination action hook as well. So you should probably look into that as well. 

Scenario 1: The WC plugin is filtering it.
Scenario 2: The WC is providing a query, but the prettify is using a rewrite_canonical filter

My guess at least.

Comment: I have already checked the rewrite rules and as you can see if you visit https://shisha-express.com/shisha-tabak/?paged=2 won't redirect you to https://shisha-express.com/shisha-tabak/page/2/ .

Comment: Try posting the page template for Shoptimize. and also the part Shoptimizer_page_before

The pagination is before the body content, so it's one of those two places IMO

Comment: `if ( ! function_exists( 'shoptimizer_woocommerce_pagination' ) ) {
 /**
  * Shoptimizer WooCommerce Pagination
  *
  * @since 1.0.0
  */
 function shoptimizer_woocommerce_pagination() {
  if ( woocommerce_products_will_display() ) {
   woocommerce_pagination();
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Looks like it's just hooking into default pagination. Try this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#return

I can't do multi-line here. but you want to look at the basic example with query.

Comment: <?php
global $wp_query;
 
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>

Comment: Do I just have to place this code in my functions.php or do I have to replace any existing code with it?

Comment: What you *could* do is remove that action that calls that code and replace with your own in your functions.php file. If you liked what happened before shoptimizer, you may be able to get away with just removing that shoptimizer action and doing nothing else.

Comment: Keep in mind, this might be solved with some setting inside Shoptimizer or Prettify. Not having access to your setup, I couldn't tell you if you can just change settings. I'd try researching a solution there first.